# Do we have something similar to Pass, Continue and Break statement in Karate?

Tags: ui-automation, karate

We are trying to test field validation and the requirement is to intentionally give null value using input method --> " " in our case.

```
       * input("#projectname", ' ')
```

It should not throw an exception and just pass that particular step without doing anything. Can we execute this using Karate?